# how to make css dropdown menu persist

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I have a pure CSS dropdown menu based around nested lists

The basic CSS:

```
#nav li ul {
  display:none;
  padding-right:3px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  font-size: 9px;
}
#nav li ul:hover, #nav li:hover ul {
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
  top:28px;
  background-color: #fc3;
}
```

The list:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="hours.php>Hours</a>
    <ul id="navhours">
      <li><a href="hours.php?id=1">Blacksburg</a></li>
      <li><a href="hours.php?id=2">Meadowbrook</a></li>
      <li><a href="hours.php?id=3">Floyd</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
 <li><a href="navabout">About Us</a>
   <ul id="navabout">
     <li><a href="director.php">Director</a></li>
     <li><a href="board.php">Board of Trustees</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to make it so that if you mouse out entirely the last menu/submenu you were hovering over didn't disappear for a second or so. I feel like this should be super easy in jQuery but my brain must be mush today because I just can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to make it so that if you mouse out entirely the last menu/submenu you were hovering over didn't disappear for a second or so???

Comment: So where's the JS code you've already tried?

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="hours.php">Hours</a>
    <ul id="navhours">
      <li><a href="hours.php?id=1">Blacksburg</a></li>
      <li><a href="hours.php?id=2">Meadowbrook</a></li>
      <li><a href="hours.php?id=3">Floyd</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
 <li><a href="navabout">About Us</a>
   <ul id="navabout">
     <li><a href="director.php">Director</a></li>
     <li><a href="board.php">Board of Trustees</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
#nav li ul {
  display:none;
  padding-right:3px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  font-size: 9px;
  position:absolute;
  top:28px;
  background-color: #fc3;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li").hover(function(){
        $("#nav li ul").stop().hide();
        $(this).find("ul").css("display","inline");
    },function(){
        $(this).find("ul").delay(1000).queue(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FsVaX/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the .mouseout(); function in jQuery, but i'd suggest you check out the Hover Intent Plugin, [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Comment: jQuery already has a `.hover()` without having to use a plugin.  You just set a timeout on the hide and clear it if the user mouses back over.